# Switching 2 ODBC database in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have 2 databases base-1 and base-2 I want to switch according some queries I need using a radioButton control to do do that

Is the best way to proceed ?

Thank you

Here my UI.R :

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Measures"),
sidebarPanel(
          radioButtons("base", "Select DB", 

         c("base1"="base-1","base2"="base-2")),
         uiOutput("selectComp")
      ),


 mainPanel(

         plotlyOutput("plot")
           ))
```

Here my server.R

```
 Library(RODBC) 

 shinyServer(function(input,output){

 refDataFrame <- reactive({

if(input$base == "base1")   {

 data_test <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="login")   

 Ref_comp <- sqlQuery(data_test, paste ("SQL query1"),as.is=T)
 odbcClose(data_test)

}

if(input$base == "base2")   {

 data_test <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="login")   

 Ref_comp <- sqlQuery(data_test, paste ("SQL query2"),as.is=T)
 odbcClose(data_test)

}

Ref_comp
})

output$selectComp <- renderUI(
  selectInput("comp","Select step", 
                     choices=refDataFrame()[["STEP_NAME"]])
              )

 })
```

Comment: As far as choosing between difference connections, there is not really a better way to do it. Are you seeing performance penalties or warnings/errors with this code? Does it work?

Comment: It works but if the query takes time or failed if I change database, is it possible it occurs an ODBC handle conflict ?

Comment: *"query takes time"* -- you can reduce the time delay by not opening/querying/closing each time. That is, create *both* connections once (outside of that reactive block), and only use the specific connection called for by the radio button.

Comment: Since this is in a Shiny app, look into the `pool` package.  It's better practice to have your app use connection pools. In this scenario you can create two connection pools, and use a radio button to switch back and forth.  Also, since the `pool` package was created by RStudio, I'd also suggest using their DBI-compliant odbc connection package, simply called `odbc`, for compatibility.

Comment: For the record, [`odbc`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc) is used by RStudio, don't know that it's written by them. They do write/maintain [`pool`](https://github.com/rstudio/pool).

Comment: I would look into the pool package. It might save you a lot of time  not having to reconnect to the databases.

Comment: I will have a look on pool package - Hope it will connect on my odbc connector with SSL certificat